# Erro ao remover div com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Eu preciso que cada vez que clique no "adicionar produto" duplique a div **.novo-produto**. E quando clique em 'remover produto' que remova a div criada. Até então funciona, mas quando você tenta adicionar novamente um produto depois de ter removido aparece o erro: undefinied.

```js
$("#adc-produto-id").click(function() {
  linha = $(".novo-produto").html();
  $("#base").append("<br />" + linha + "<br />");
  $('#remover-produto').click(function() {
    $('.novo-produto').remove('.novo-produto');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="novo-produto">
    <h4>Qual a quantidade?</h4>
    <input type="number" name="quantidade" placeholder="Quantidade">
    <h4>Qual a superfície?</h4>
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select>
        <option value="">Superfície</option>
        <option value="alvenaria">Alvenaria</option>
        <option value="metal">Metal</option>
        <option value="madeira">Madeira</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <h4>Qual a embalagem?</h4>
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select>
        <option value="">Embalagem</option>
        <option value="litro">800 ml</option>
        <option value="galao">3,2 Litros</option>
        <option value="balde">16 Litros</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="base"></div>
  <div id="adc-produto-id" class="adc-produto">
    Adicionar produto
  </div>
  <div id="remover-produto"> remover produto</div>
  <input class="btn-enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, tem dois problemas: o primeiro é que a função remover estava dentro da de adicionar e a segunda é que você estava apagando o div de referência (aquele que você guarda dentro da variável 'linha'.
De um modo bem simples, deu uma corrigida nisso e coloquei a função para apagar o 'último' produto inserido. Outra implementação pode ser feita para cada produto ter um delete.

```js
$("#adc-produto-id").click(function() {
  linha = $(".novo-produto").html();
  $("#base").append('<div class="novo-produto">' + linha + '</div>');
});

$('#remover-produto').click(function() {
  $('#base .novo-produto').last().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="novo-produto">
    <h4>Qual a quantidade?</h4>
    <input type="number" name="quantidade" placeholder="Quantidade">
    <h4>Qual a superfície?</h4>
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select>
        <option value="">Superfície</option>
        <option value="alvenaria">Alvenaria</option>
        <option value="metal">Metal</option>
        <option value="madeira">Madeira</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <h4>Qual a embalagem?</h4>
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select>
        <option value="">Embalagem</option>
        <option value="litro">800 ml</option>
        <option value="galao">3,2 Litros</option>
        <option value="balde">16 Litros</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="base"></div>
  <div id="adc-produto-id" class="adc-produto">
    Adicionar produto
  </div>
  <div id="remover-produto">remover <b>último</b> produto</div>
  <input class="btn-enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```